# Compare two Dates in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, linq-to-entities

Controller:

```
public JsonResult TestArray(string id)
{
    //warehouse_order warehouse_order = new warehouse_order();
    int[] finishedOrders = new int[8];
    int countErledigt;

    var stichtag = DateTime.Today;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        stichtag = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-i);
        countErledigt = db.warehouse_order.Where(c => c.end_time == stichtag ).Count();
        finishedOrders[i] = countErledigt;
    }

    int[] test = finishedOrders;

    return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Erledigt am")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> end_time { get; set; }
```

I havn't been able to compare the two dates in the controller.
    any Idea how i could do that?
    Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `end_time` property has type of `Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset>`, but `stichtag` has type of `DateTime`, you can't directly compare them.

You should either extract `DateTime` part from `end_time` or wrap `stichtag` into `DateTimeOffset`.

Since in LINQ to Entities you cannot use properties that are not mapped to a database column in a `Where` expression - your only option is second one:

```
var stichtag = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-i));
countErledigt = db.warehouse_order.Where(c => c.end_time == stichtag).Count();
```

Comment: Thx Andy, but It thorws an Exception ( System.NotSupportedException)

Comment: And what is exception text? Are you sure this code throws it, not some other? This code is pretty straightforward and should not thow this kind of exception.

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties

Comment: Oh, I've missed the fact it is LINQ to Entities query. See updated answer.

Comment: I managed it doing this:

countErledigt = db.warehouse_order
                  .Where(c => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.end_time) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(stichtag))
                  .Count();

Thanks Andy